# Page Link gets prefixed in Wordpress menu link

Tags: php, wordpress

Sorry if this is dumb, I'm a newbie to php and wordpress. I've installed the theme socialreach on my [WordPress site](http://reach.smcademy.com). Now in header, in the mycampaigns dropdown, I want user to be redirected to site homepage, so I edited the header code to:

```
<a href="reach.smacademy.com"><i class="fa fa-rocket"></i><?php _e('My campaigns', 'reach'); ?></a>
```

but on the page it comes as `reach.smacademy.com/reach.smacademy.com`.
What's the issue? Is it related to some theme code?

Comment: you need to be logged in to see the link

Comment: @m.cekiera: if you edit questions containing links to live sites that exhibit a particular problem, you can usually remove the link entirely. We discourage this practice, since it renders the question useless for future readers once the problem is resolved.

Comment: @halfer I'm sorry and totally agree, it was mistake in editing, I wanted to make "wp site" as a hiperlink, but I did something wrong. I will put more attention to editing in future

Comment: @m.cekiera: no worries, it's all good `:-)`.

Comment: @cyberdoc, http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<a href="http://reach.smacademy.com"><i class="fa fa-rocket"></i><?php _e('My campaigns', 'reach'); ?></a>
```

Your current link is relative to the page you are on so it appends the link to the end of your current page.

Comment: Great.. quite dumb of me :D

Comment: no problem, actually @Danijel has a better answer as it uses the wordpress function, I dont use wordpress so did not know the home_url() function but you would need to update the home link everywhere if it changes unless you use the Danijel solution

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`home_url`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/home_url) function to retrieve the home URL for the current site.

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>">
    <i class="fa fa-rocket"></i>
    <?php _e('My campaigns', 'reach'); ?>
</a>
```